# How should I handle push notifications in react native firebase app if closed or running in background

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

first if app closed:

```
this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications()
.getInitialNotification()
.then((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
if (notificationOpen) {
    // App was opened by a notification
    // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
    const action = notificationOpen.action;
    // Get information about the notification that was opened
    const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
}
});
```

second if app running on background:

```
this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications()
    .onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen: NotificationOpen) => {
    // Get the action triggered by the notification being opened
    const action = notificationOpen.action;
    // Get information about the notification that was opened
    const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
 });
```

how to join code first and second.

reference : Here's [a link](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase-docs/blob/master/docs/notifications/receiving-notifications.md)!

or how to whip an application closed or running in the background react native?